# Using grep to get ip address

Tags: grep

I am learning regular expressions and as aa practice I tried grep'ing an ip address but it fails to get any results. I tried it out on VSCode and it works. Anyone can enligheten me where did I go wrong?

```
echo 192.168.1.1 | grep -e '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'
```

Comment: Related: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) - in particular note that the `+` quantifier is part of the *extended* regular expression syntax and `\d` is from the perl (PCRE) extension set

Comment: Note that when you figure out how to get your `grep` to understand `\d` as "a digit", you still would match e.g. `000.0002222.020202020.020.0.0.0.0.0` with that expression.

Comment: Thanks for answering, didn't know there were so many types. this is really confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep -P`:

```
-P, --perl-regexp         PATTERNS are Perl regular expressions
```

Comment: It works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that regular expressions are not really meant for parsing things like IPv4 addresses. You can try to do it, to a certain level of accuracy:

Your expression `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+` would match any four groups of digits separated by a dot, if `\d` matched a digit on its own.

Keep in mind that regular expressions [have many *flavors*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) and results may vary, depending on the engine being used. When you use `grep -P` as suggested in another answer, you change the parsing engine.

In [Matching IPv4 Addresses - Regular Expressions Cookbook by O'Reilly](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html) you have some examples.

This checks for (just) an IP address, not many checks though, `299.299.111.1` would pass:

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$
```

The other examples in the page try to narrow down the detection to get a valid IP address, see what they propose for accurate extraction from longer text and you'll know why IPv4 addresses are not a good playground for regular expressions:

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}↵
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```